# Capturing image of HTML table using Python

Tags: python, html, csv

I know one can generate html from csv, but how to turn that HTML into an image using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [python-webkit2png](https://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png) project to convert HTML code to an image using webkit engine (same as Chrome uses)

Answer (score 1):

One method of doing this is to

- Generate a HTML file
- Open this file in a web browser controlled by Python using [Selenium WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html). For the server-side you can make a headless browser installation. Both Firefox and Chrome should be good.
- Call [WebDriver screenshot](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=screenshot#how-to-take-screenshot-of-the-current-window) function to capture the rendered output as image

If the image is larger than the (virtual) screen used by the browser then Firefox has some addons to capture the whole web page as an image.

[Here is one of my old scripts where I was capturing pages generated JavaScript to images on the server](https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/bin/create_bg_thumbnails.py).